# How to run the postgres query with date as input on the column with timestamp in long format

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, sql-timestamp

I want to query postgres database table which has the column with timestamp in long milliseconds. But I have the time in date format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"  like this. How can I convert this date format to long milliseconds to run the query?

Comment: Timestamp values should be stored in `timestamp` columns, not `bigint`

Answer (score 0):

You can either convert your long value to a proper timestamp:

```
select *
from the_table
where to_timestamp(the_millisecond_column / 1000) = timestamp '2020-10-05 07:42'
```

Or extract the seconds from the timestamp value :

```
select *
from the_table
where the_millisecond_column = extract(epoch from timestamp '2020-10-05 07:42') * 1000
```

The better solution is however to convert that column to a proper `timestamp` column to avoid the constant conversion between (milliseconds) and proper `timestamp` values